# C++ Builder и JSON

Tags: json, c++builder

Проблема состоит в следующем - надо распарсить JSON в программе, но библиотека `System.JSON.hpp`, которая для этого используется, не находится компилятором.

```
[C++ Error] Unit1.cpp(6): E2209 Unable to open include file 'System.JSON.hpp'
```

Каким образом можно решить эту проблему ? И есть ли какие-то рабочие библиотеки для подобной задачи?

Comment: а где сам файл находится?

Comment: В настройках проекта нужно указать каталог с этим hpp-файлом.

Comment: я его искал среди библиотек, искал также DBXJSON, но обе они отсутствуют. Если есть линк на скачивание - расшарьте пожалуйста, ибо его я не нашел

Answer (score 1):

С++ Builder что я использую не содержит в себе данные библиотеки. В открытом доступе находится библиотека для работы с JSON - jsoncpp, которая предоставляет весь необходимый функционал.